# How can I simulate a USB printer to LPT on Linux?

Tags: linux, printing, lpt

I have an Intermec printer connected on an USB port to my computer, the computer doesn't have a parallel port.

I want to send some raw commands to the printer, the printer interprets the file send as commands only if it is send on the parallel port (LPT). At the momment, the printer connected on USB will print the commands as text on the paper.

In Windows this can be achieved by sharing the printer on the network and then using the following:

```
NET USE LPT1: \\127.0.0.1\Printer /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Can I do the same in Linux?

Comment: What command are you trying to send?

Comment: You want to rename the printer from "/dev/usbsomething" to "/dev/lpsomething"? In old Linux versions "/dev" was an ordinary directory so this was possible. Nowadays this is no longer possible. However the "/dev/usbsomething" device can be used exactly the same way as "/dev/lpsomething". (In Windows USB drivers do not have a device name like "LPTUSB1:" so the "net use" is necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set printer in raw mode. In cups\ppd\lpoptions set raw mode.

```
raw=true, lp -o raw
```

Comment: the: "lp -d (printer name) -o raw filename" worked seamless. Thanks!